# Get the intersection of points (lat,long) and a specific area

Tags: postgresql, geometry, gis, postgis, latitude-longitude

I've recently put my hands on **Postgres** together with **Postgis** and I can't seem to figure it out what's the right syntax.

**Problem**: I need a list of ids of the points which are in a certain area. *lat* and *lon* are two columns of type `bigint` and the `cluj.the_geom` is a `polygon`.

> link_geometry: link_id | lat |lon
>
> cluj: the_geom

```
SELECT link_id 
FROM rou_country_20656215.link_geometry r, cluj 
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_PointFromText((CAST(r.lon AS float)/100000, CAST(r.lat AS float)/100000), 4326), cluj.the_geom)
```

I get the following error message:

[image: ERROR]

I mention that I don't have access to modify the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've solved it like this, apart from the record interpretation I was missing setting the SRID.

```
SELECT link_id,
FROM rou_country_20656215.rdf_link_geometry r, rou_country_20656215.cluj c
WHERE ST_Intersects(
           ST_SetSRID(
              ST_MakePoint(CAST(r.lon AS float)/10^5, CAST(r.lat AS float)/10^5),4326),c.the_geom)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses around your two `CAST` expressions, and the comma between them, result in that expression being interpreted as a record.  That needs to be a string instead. Assuming that your latitude and longitude values are text (implicit in your code), then this should produce the kind of expression that you need:

```
SELECT link_id 
FROM rou_country_20656215.link_geometry r, cluj 
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(
        ST_PointFromText(cast(cast(r.lon AS float)/100000 as text) 
            || cast(cast(r.lat AS float)/100000 as text)), 4326)), 
            cluj.the_geom);
```